# Distance in advanced digitizing not working properly?

Tags: qgis-3, distance, measurements

I'm trying to remap a papermap of a festival with QGIS.
I tried to use the advanced digitalizing tool to set the right distances and angles between the point but noticed that the distance I put in isn't correctly set in the map.

To reproduce the problem do the following steps:

1. Load google satellite map
2. Go to coordinate X: 1041106.209718  Y: 7007221.582073 (this should be on a small airport in northern Germany)
3. Create a temporary layer with geometry set to polygon
4. Activate the advanced digitalizing tool and set the first point of the polygon at the given coordinate
5. Press D on the keyboard and enter any distance you want to (I used 25,611)
   and set the second point and any third point so the polygon is valid
6. Use the measuring tool to check if the first segment has the desired length.
   In my case it was permanently too short.

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

I am using QGIS 3.8 on Linux Mint 19 Tara

Comment: this is probably a difference in how the distance is measured in the 2 cases, once properly accounting for the ellipsoid and once using the web mercator projection that the map is in. Germany is sufficiently far north for there to be an appreciable difference.

Comment: Well, I also though of this, but I wasn't sure if this could be the problem...
Do you have any idea how to do this task with the ellipsoid measurement?

Also if this is the problem, in my opinion this would be a important ToDo for the next update...